# Separating all individual letters in a .fasta file into one letter per column of a matrix

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta

I want to do the following in R.

I have a .fasta file containing about 90 DNA gene sequences like this:

```
>3 dna:chromosome chromosome:ASM162521v1:3:6424947:6434108:1
GTTAGATTTTCAAATTTTTCCAAAGTTTTATAATTTTCATTTTTTTAAGAATTCCATTTT
TTTCGAATTTTTTCGAATTTTTTAGCTTTTTAGAAGCTTTCAGTTTTTAAGTTTTCTTAA #(.. contains up to 9300 letters)

>6 dna:chromosome chromosome:ASM162521v1:6:27534931:27544030:1
GTATAGGTTCTAAAAAGACTGTTTGAATTTCCATATAGGCATATAGCTTTAACCATGAGC
TGTTACTAGCCTTTTGCTGATTTTAAGCTTGCTATGAACTATTGTAACATTTTGTTTATT #(.. contains up to 9300 letters)
```

I want to separate each individual letter into a separate column of a matrix like so:

[Please click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5fnU.png)

The final output must have the dimensions of [as many rows as there are sequences and as many columns as there are letters in my file].

And the output has to be written into an excel file.

This is how far I've gotten

```
input_file <- as.matrix(input_file)

template_matrix <- matrix(,91,9300)

for (i in 1:nrow(input_file)) {
  current_row <- input_file[i,1]
  strip_char <- strsplit(current_row, "")
  first_char <- strip_char[1]

  if (first_char == ">"){
    template_matrix[i,1] <- current_row
    new_i = i+1
    for (j in new_i:nrow(input_file)){
      j_current_row <- input_file[j, 1]
      j_strip_char <- strsplit(j_current_row, "")
      j_first_char <- j_strip_char[1]

      if(j_first_char != ">"){
        for (k in new_i:){
          template_matrix[i, ] #I'VE GOTTEN HOPELESSLY LOST SOMEWHERE
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless all of your sequences have the exact same number of bases, putting them into a matrix is a bad idea. It might be a bad idea even so because the matrix will be positively huge.

Either way, you can use the [{seqinr}](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seqinr/index.html) package:

```
sequences = seqinr::read.fasta(filename)
names = vapply(sequences, attr, character(1L), 'Annot')
results = cbind(names, do.call(rbind, sequences))
```

But as mentioned, I don’t think having this matrix is necessarily the most convenient representation so I’d stop after the first step.

Comment: The sequences are indeed of unequal bases. How do I go about it in this case?
Also, there is no further data manipulation required once this step has been completed (i.e. once the output that I require is in a .csv file), this is so that if I want, I can locate at a particular column- all bases in as many sequences as I want quickly from the excel sheet without having to type in a code again. Does this make sense?